# fish: “gnome-control-center” terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)

Tags: ubuntu

I came across a strange problem after I upgraded to Ubuntu 19.10: The settings disappeared from the menus!

after a quick search, I installed gnome-control-center (`sudo apt install gnome-control-center`) and things went back to normal.

Few hours later it is gone again! I reinstalled it (`sudo apt install gnome-control-center`) but didn't fix it.
I tried running it in terminal but I get this result:

```
$ gnome-control-center     
/sys/firmware/dmi/tables/smbios_entry_point: Permission denied
/dev/mem: Permission denied
fish: “gnome-control-center” terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

I tried with sudo (?!) but it got weirder:

```
$ sudo gnome-control-center
**
ERROR:../shell/cc-shell-model.c:458:cc_shell_model_set_panel_visibility: assertion failed: (valid)
Bail out! ERROR:../shell/cc-shell-model.c:458:cc_shell_model_set_panel_visibility: assertion failed: (valid)
fish: “sudo gnome-control-center” terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)
```

Anyone has any idea why this is happening of what those errors means?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem and the following command fixed it:

```
$ gsettings reset org.gnome.ControlCenter last-panel
```

Source: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/-/issues/346